# Any differences between Activate[...] vs ReplaceAll[...,Inactive[f_]-f>]?

Tags: evaluation, expression-manipulation

I can activate an expression with `Inactive` objects such as

```
expr = Inactive[f][Inactive[f][x], y] + Inactive[f]
```

by applying `Activate`:

```
Activate[expr]
(*f + f[f[x],y]*)
```

But also, I can achieve the same task with `ReplaceAll`:

```
expr /. Inactive[f] :> f
```

Should I be aware of any differences between these two methods of activation?  Or is `Activate` *really* just `ReplaceAll` under the hood?  Or maybe it is the same as `Replace[expr,Inactive[f] :> f,{0,Infinity},Heads->True` due to similarities in options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is at least one difference in evaluation between [`Activate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html) and either of your proposed equivalents, for a malformed [`Inactive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) expression:

```
Inactive[1 + 1, 5] // Activate
Inactive[1 + 1, 5] /. Inactive[x_] :> x
Replace[Inactive[1 + 1, 5], Inactive[x_] :> x, {0, -1}, Heads -> True]
```

> ```
> 2
>
> Inactive[1 + 1, 5]
>
> Inactive[1 + 1, 5]
> ```

Therefore the replacement appears to be closer to:

```
Inactive[1 + 1, 5] /. Inactive[x_, ___] :> x
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

This however does not match with nested Inactives:

```
Inactive[Inactive[a]] // Activate
Inactive[Inactive[a]] /. Inactive[x_, ___] :> x
```

> ```
> a
>
> Inactive[a]
> ```

But the modified `Replace` form does:

```
Replace[Inactive[Inactive[a]], Inactive[x_, ___] :> x, {0, -1}, Heads -> True]
```

> ```
> a
> ```

I have yet to make this behave differently from `Activate`.

Comment: So perhaps it is equivalent to `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`) with your modified rule `Inactive[x_, ___] :> x`?

Comment: @QuantumDot That could be less efficient than the `Replace` form and I don't see the advantage of it, and `ReplaceRepeated` doesn't supports `Heads` does it?